# URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName doesn't seem to work with csv extension

Tags: java, csv, mime-types, urlconnection

I have been using `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(String fname)` to detect what mime type I need to use in my headers to return different documents.

It was working fine until I tested with `fname = "test.csv";`. I can make it work with `test.jpg` or `test.pdf` but not with `test.csv`.

```java
String fname = "test.csv";

String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fname);

System.out.println(mimeType);
```

I have no issue getting the good mimetype for pdf and jpg extension but receive null with the csv one.

I can't seem to find any reason on google as to why it doesn't work. **Is it normal behavior or am I missing something from the documentation ?**

As a side note, I know of other ways to get the mime type from the filename but was wondering about this.

Comment: @KJ Yes, but it doesn't change the fact that I get `null`, not `text/plain`. And even if that was the case `text/csv` does exists so why wouldn't you get it for a `x.csv` filename ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jvm brings along a list of file names and their mime types. For example openjdk specifies them for [windows](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/net/www/content-types.properties) and [linux](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/classes/sun/net/www/content-types.properties).

You can override these definitions by specifying a jvm property `content.types.user.table` pointing to your definition of `content-types.properties` as specified by [URLConnection#getFileNameMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getFileNameMap()).

Support for csv was only added recently with https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8273655

Comment: I'm using openjdk so it does makes sense. Thanks ! (I will accept your answer soon)

Comment: Actually I just looked in the openjdk and can find in both linux and windows `text/csv: \
 description=CSV File;\
 file_extensions=.csv;` so it should be supported ?

Comment: @PhilippeB. I have removed the non-support of csv from this answer. I'm have no idea why it doesn't work for you. Have you checked the `content-types.properties` in your local jvm installation?

Comment: @PhilippeB. csv was only added recently. I have edited this answer. So you probably don't have an up-to-date enough jvm installed.

Comment: I can't seem to find the content-types.properties in my openjdk, it is present for my java 8 version but not my java 11. I have the java 11 1.0.10.9 version and it seems that there is no csv support as per this [example](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/net/www/content-types.properties). So your post was actually right ! Thanks

Comment: @PhilippeB. I was also unable to find that file. I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699840/how-to-inspect-jvm-module-contents-from-the-command-line because of that.