# Get extension and mime type from bytes[] in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a servlet that queries the bytes of a file, reads and responds to the content.

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
```

I need to know what the extension of the read file is, so I can name the file with the extension correctly.

Searching I found the following:

```
URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

This doesn't support all file types, like pdf for example. I need a more assertive solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName doesn't seem to work with csv extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72698182/urlconnection-guesscontenttypefromname-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-csv-extension)

Comment: You might be facing the same issue I was facing, it seems weird that it doesn't support pdf, you might want to check your jdk version and see what types are supported. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699840/how-to-inspect-jvm-module-contents-from-the-command-line)

Comment: "I need to know what the extension of the read file is ...". You know the file's filename (variable `my_file`). So extract the extension from `my_file` and you are done.

Comment: And you should wrap the FileInputStream in a BufferedInputStream. This can make a huge performance difference e.g. while reading from a network file system.